# Copy smaps file to a memfd_create file using a pipe: error splicing (EINVAL)

Tags: c, linux, pipe, filesystems

I want to copy `/proc/self/smaps` to a temporary file created with `memfd_create`, using an intermediary pipe:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void err(int status, char const* ctx)
{
    if (status == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %s: %s\n", ctx, strerrorname_np(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
}

#define MB 1024 * 1024
unsigned copy_fds(int fd_target, int fd_source)
{
    int pipefd[2];
    int status;

    status = pipe2(pipefd, 0); err(status, "creating pipe");
    status = fcntl(pipefd[1], F_SETPIPE_SZ, 1 * MB); err(status, "allocating buf for the pipe");
    status = ftruncate(fd_target, 1 * MB); err(status, "allocating space for the memfd-file");

    ssize_t spliced = splice(fd_source, NULL, pipefd[1], NULL, 1 * MB, 0); err(spliced, "splice1");
    ssize_t written = splice(pipefd[0], NULL, fd_target, NULL, spliced, 0); err(written, "write1");

    return written;
}

int main()
{
    int fd_smaps = open("/proc/self/smaps", O_RDONLY); err(fd_smaps, "opening");
    int fd_tmp = memfd_create("smaps", 0); err(fd_tmp, "creating");

    printf("Copied: %u\n", copy_fds(fd_tmp, fd_smaps));

    close(fd_smaps);
    close(fd_tmp);

    return 0;
}
```

But it fails in the first `splice` call with `EINVAL`. What can be the problem?

**NOTE:** My linux kernel is 5.15

**NOTE:** Related articles talking about this problem:

- The original thread where a regression was discovered (regarding procfs not supporting splicing, when before 5.10 it worked): https://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/2010.3/02776.html
- Contextual information about the issue (related with security): https://lwn.net/Articles/896267/

Comment: One of the reasons for EINVAL listed in [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) is "The target filesystem doesn't support splicing." I bet that's the case here. I know procfs doesn't support other operations like seeking...

Comment: I think I have just bad luck. My linux kernel is 5.15, and it looks like in version 5.10 a bug was introduced that made procfs to not support splicing anymore, and I'm trying to know now in which version the functionality is again restored: https://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/2010.3/02776.html

Comment: My linux kernel is 6.4.0 and it is still not working.

Comment: @cforler I have added a note in the question with two links. It looks like proc has a partial support for splicing (it depends on the specific file you want to read from).